# Does PhoneGap Provide UI Controls Styling Like Ionic Does?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap-4.0.0

What I mean by that. Is that if you look through [Ionics](http://ionicframework.com) documentation, you'll see they list all the [UI controls](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/) that you have at your disposal and how you can use them.

My company currently would be open to using Ionic over PhoneGap, however we need BlackBerry as well as Windows Phone support - of which Ionic does not cover yet. I have read through PhoneGap's docs and I just can't seem to find anything related to how they handle UI components and the styling thereof.

Do they have their own components like Ionic? Are there third party frameworks that can help with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap or Cordova don't provide UI elements, you can write HTML/CSS/JS for webview yourself or you can use some other framework like jQuery Mobile, Sencha Touch, Famo.us
Ionic framework works with Windows Phone but its not perfect but i don't think any of frameworks support BlackBerry.

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually found something called Onsen UI that's looking promising.

Answer (score 0):

- look on [materialize](http://materializecss.com/), he provide good stuff for modern ui.
- of course you can use [polymer](https://www.polymer-project) paper componen

but ionic provide usefull angular directive, and a complete toolbox. MoreOver ionic.io provide atractive services like deploy, push, etc

Comment: I would use Ionic in a heart beat but.. No official Windows Phone and Blackberry support :(

Comment: i never use ionic for blackberry, but cordova provide support for him, and ionic is only an framework who run in cordova. moreOver, blackberry provide a modern webview, so i think you can use ionic with him. soonds like you have to test it :)